# Blue screen error with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod, windows-error-reporting

I formatted my computer using a Windows XP cd, then I decided to install Windows 7 Pro. After some downtime, the blue screen appeared. This time just restarted the computer.

Thinking it would be a mistake on the version of Windows installed, I installed Windows 7 Ultimate. After a few hours I put to update and went to sleep. Upon waking, there was the blue screen again. I wonder if someone could help me identify the error.

Even before formatting I used Windows 8 and he never had this problem.
My hardware: 500gb HD, Intel i3 processor, 4GB RAM.

Any idea how to fix this?

Image of the blue screen error: http://bit.ly/1etSQuq

---

Update:

BlueScreenViewer showed this:

112513-67408-01.dmp 25/11/2013 06:57:02 SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED 0x1000007e  0x80000004  0x924cd451  0x8df97ac4  0x8df976a0  igdkmd32.sys    igdkmd32.sys+2ae451 Intel Graphics Kernel Mode Driver   Intel Graphics Accelerator Drivers for Windows 8(R) Intel Corporation   9.17.10.3347    32-bit  igdkmd32.sys+2ae451 ntkrnlpa.exe+20ab34 ntkrnlpa.exe+c6144  ntkrnlpa.exe+7daab      C:\Windows\MiniDump\112513-67408-01.dmp 4   15  7601    149.504 25/11/2013 10:21:33

That means I installed the driver referring to windows 8 and not the windows 7? If yes, how can I uninstall it?

Comment: Both of these installations were using an actual license to their respective products? Use a program like BlueScreenViewer to and post the information. Have you install **ALL** drivers for all your devices?  **Update your question to include this information.**

Comment: The Ultimate version of Windows already come with launcher (not the original Windows). I scanned in the intel website and everything went ok with the drivers. But I'm currently using DriverEasy to install some drivers it showed. When finished installing all of them, I'll perform this BlueScreenViewer.

This blue screen image was this morning, so far has not reappeared. I'll keep updated here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use "driver" programs.  Find the drivers for each device yourself and install them.

Comment: Here is the result of bulescreenviewer, @Ramhound.

Comment: Use the device manager to uninstall the driver. What CPU do you have?  The crash is caused by the `Intel Graphics Accelerator Driver" simply uninstalling it and leaving it uninstalled will improve the stability of your system.

Comment: I went to the device manager but did not find any driver with that name. I'll wait to see if the blue screen appears again or if I installed the drivers solved the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It would be listed under the `graphic display` devices.

Answer (score 3):

`igdkmd32.sys` is the driver for your Intel HD graphic which is build in to the Intel i3.

Download the latest driver from Intel and install it:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=HD%20Graphics